# How to reject an advisor for master's thessis?

Tags: masters, advisor, interpersonal-issues

(I could not find the same question. If this has been asked before please let me know.)

I wrote an e-mail to a professor to be his student and he responded with his area of interests. Then I wrote for further information but he did not respond for couple of days. So I contacted another advisor and we agreed to work together.

Few hours later the first advisor replied saying he could give me something to work.

How can I let him know that I agreed to work with another professor? Did I do a mistake by not waiting more for his response and contacting other advisor?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple note of thanks, but that you have made another arrangement, is enough. Only the future will tell whether you made a mistake or not.

Don't worry about it. The professor will be fine. There is nothing insulting or unusual about what you've done.

Comment: Thank you Professor. Maybe he gets dozens of e-mails like this and will not care much as much as I do, right?

Comment: Probably. And he is busy enough that it's no problem. Just don't forget to say thanks. Note that a lot of people contact professors in parallel, rather than one after another, so the time isn't really an issue.